# How do i get current user Fullname to display in a form validation message

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am using a Wordpress plugin called Ultimate Membership Pro which is using Ajax call to validate Username  in the Registration form. However, I would like to retrieve the full name of the user when a Username that has been registered is trying to register again.

Example - I want the Validation message to say: This username has been taken by John Doe

I have tried to manipulate a filename called indeed-membership-pro.php file in the plugin directory.

```
//I added this code under the function
//I called a global method
                global $current_user;
        $uid = get_user_by('login', $value);



                            case 'user_login':
                if (!validate_username($value)){
                    $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_error_username_msg'];
                }
                if (username_exists($value)) {

      //I concatenate the error message with the input username to get the user ID. But i need the user FirstName and Lastname


                    $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_username_taken_msg'] . $uid->ID;
                }
                break;




function ihc_check_value_field($type='',  $value='', $val2='',  $register_msg=array()){

//I called a global method
                global $current_user;
        $uid = get_user_by('login', $value);


    if (isset($value) && $value!=''){

        switch ($type){
            case 'user_login':
                if (!validate_username($value)){
                    $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_error_username_msg'];
                }
                if (username_exists($value)) {

//I am able to get the user ID But i need First Name and last Name

                    $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_username_taken_msg']. $uid->ID;
                }
                break;
            case 'user_email':
                if (!is_email($value)) {
                    $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_invalid_email_msg'];
                }
                if (email_exists($value)){
                    $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_email_is_taken_msg'];
                }
                $blacklist = get_option('ihc_email_blacklist');
                if(isset($blacklist)){
                    $blacklist = explode(',',preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $blacklist));

                    if( count($blacklist) > 0 && in_array($value,$blacklist)){
                        $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_email_is_taken_msg'];
                    }
                }

                break;
            case 'confirm_email':
                if ($value==$val2){
                    $return = 1;
                } else {
                    $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_emails_not_match_msg'];
                }
                break;
            case 'pass1':
                $register_metas = ihc_return_meta_arr('register');
                if ($register_metas['ihc_register_pass_options']==2){
                    //characters and digits
                    if (!preg_match('/[a-z]/', $value)){
                        $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_pass_letter_digits_msg'];
                    }
                    if (!preg_match('/[0-9]/', $value)){
                        $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_pass_letter_digits_msg'];
                    }
                } else if ($register_metas['ihc_register_pass_options']==3){
                    //characters, digits and one Uppercase letter
                    if (!preg_match('/[a-z]/', $value)){
                        $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_pass_let_dig_up_let_msg'];
                    }
                    if (!preg_match('/[0-9]/', $value)){
                        $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_pass_let_dig_up_let_msg'];
                    }
                    if (!preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $value)){
                        $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_pass_let_dig_up_let_msg'];
                    }
                }
                //check the length of password
                if($register_metas['ihc_register_pass_min_length']!=0){
                    if (strlen($value)<$register_metas['ihc_register_pass_min_length']){
                        $return = str_replace( '{X}', $register_metas['ihc_register_pass_min_length'], $register_msg['ihc_register_pass_min_char_msg'] );
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 'pass2':
                if ($value==$val2){
                    $return = 1;
                } else {
                    $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_pass_not_match_msg'];
                }
                break;
            case 'tos':
                if ($value==1){
                    $return = 1;
                } else {
                    $return = $register_msg['ihc_register_err_tos'];
                }
                break;

            default:
                //required conditional field
                $check = ihc_required_conditional_field_test($type, $value);
                if ($check){
                    $return = $check;
                } else {
                    $return = 1;
                }
                break;
        }
        if (empty($return)){
            $return = 1;
        }
        return $return;
    } else {
        $check = ihc_required_conditional_field_test($type, $value);//Check for required conditional field
        if ($check){
            return $check;
        } else {
            return $register_msg['ihc_register_err_req_fields'];
        }
    }
}



add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_ihc_ap_reset_custom_banner", "ihc_ap_reset_custom_banner");
add_action('wp_ajax_ihc_ap_reset_custom_banner', 'ihc_ap_reset_custom_banner');
```

Comment: A very bad idea from a safety point of view to reveal the name of an account-holder to a complete stranger. Complete no-go.

Comment: I completely agree with you. But there is nothing i can do as this is a requirement from a client.

Answer (score 0):

`$user_object->display_name` is what you are looking for.

This given, it may not be a good idea to reveal user data such as first name & last name as part of the error message.

Comment: It is part of the requirements, A user-name is going to be inform of an account number which will be giving to maybe 5 group of people to access the system, Hence they want the new user to be notify that the account number they are trying to register has been previously registered by John Doe. Hence the user can contact John Doe and request for password from John Doe.